# Why is my IP camera image sometimes updating really slowly?

Tags: jquery, html, ip-camera

I am using a jQuery script to periodically update the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element in a web page. The problem I am experiencing is that the image is not always updated at the `setInterval`, but this is only in my web page. Accessing the camera UI directly shows that it is actually updating much more frequently.

Why is this happening, and is there a better solution to achieve what I am attempting?

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user = "usename";
    var pass = "password";
    var IP = "1.2.3.4";

    var cameraFeed = "http://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + IP + "/cgi-bin/camera?resolution=270&quality=1";

    var topImage = $('#topImage');

    setInterval(function(){
        d = new Date();
        topImage.attr('src', cameraFeed + "&timestamp=" + d.getTime());
    }, 5000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<img id="topImage" width="274px">
```

[html](/questions/tagged/html) tag in case there is a better solution based in the HTML.

The camera model number is BB-ST162A

Comment: code shown will change the srcevery 5 seconds, assuming no other errors are thrown. Sounds like your issue is with the generation of the image or possibly errors thrown from other code. Anything showing in your developer console?

Comment: I had a look at the Network tab in Chrome's console, and it looks like the view is updated only when it is fully caught up with loading all the images. E.g. if three images are still loading, it will not show one of those three images when it finishes loading, but show the latest image only after loading all images. So, maybe the problem lies in using `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, the execution of setInterval in js is not guaranteed to
  be scheduled exactly after the delay. In your case this mean that it
  can be scheduled also after five and a half seconds.
- Second, the network usually has delay during trasmission, so your webpage may need some
  seconds (if the connection isn't fast enough) to download each
  "frame" (image).
- Third, access directly to your camera from the UI
  may be under UDP protocol (your request seems to be under HTTP and so
  TCP), as you know UDP is faster than TCP even if UDP may miss some
  frames.

I hope this gives you insight, but if you need some other explanation I'll be glad to answer.
I apologise for my english but it is not my mother tongue.

**Edit after comments:**

I thought of two solutions, but I'm not sure they'll work.

First solution - try loading image asyncronusly by Image object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user = "usename";
    var pass = "password";
    var IP = "1.2.3.4";

    var cameraFeed = "http://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + IP + "/cgi-bin/camera?resolution=270&quality=1";



    setInterval(function(){
        d = new Date();
       var img=new Image();
       img.src=
       img.onload = function() {
        var topImage = $('#topImage');
         topImage.attr('src',this.src );
       };
       img.source=cameraFeed + "&timestamp=" + d.getTime();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Second solution: try using only Image Object to get a continuous feed:

```
function loadImage(){
           var user = "usename";
           var pass = "password";
           var IP = "1.2.3.4";
           var cameraFeed = "http://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + IP + "/cgi-bin/camera?resolution=270&quality=1";
           var d = new Date();
           var img=new Image();
           img.src=
           img.onload = function() {
            var topImage = $('#topImage');
             topImage.attr('src',this.src );
             loadImage(); //here you can put a setTimeout to wait some time before start downloading the next "frame"
           };
           img.source=cameraFeed + "&timestamp=" + d.getTime();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  loadImage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I managed to get the camera to update more frequently (not wait for all pending images to be loaded and display an image as soon as it is loaded). I will look into the specific reason and share it here when I have a chance to look at the source.

Comment: `img.onload` is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I don't understand what is `img.src=`. Is a part of the code missing?